# How would I set the value of a variable to the results of a query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has two variables. They are `@DateLeft` and `@DateRight`. `@DateLeft` is the variable that I would like to set equal to the results of a query.`@DateRight = GETDATE()`. I have the following data:

**EDIT 2: Added 'Distance' column**

```
Date         Code    Distance       **The values in the distance column are arbitrary and they are there for example's sake
11/23/2015   A       456
12/28/2015   B       2163
1/25/2016    C       203
4/30/2015    D       8921
```

My stored procedure is supposed to use `@DateLeft` and `@DateRight` to determine a date range that controls another calculation. These dates are the most recent dates that a particular event occurred. I am supposed to use the dates in the `Date` column as the `@DateLeft` value for each different code in the `Code` column. For example, the procedure should run and get `11/23/2015` as the value for `@DateLeft` for code `A`. It will then do its calculation and move on and get `12/28/2015` for code `B`, and so on. I don't know how to perform this calculation so that it doesn't have to run the whole procedure again to do its calculations with a different date for `@DateLeft`. My query for the end result looks something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TraveledDistance) AS Distance, Code 
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
Time BETWEEN @DateLeft AND @DateRight
```

I would like to do something like this maybe (I'm open to suggestions, of course):

```
SET @DateLeft = Select Date From SampleTable
                Group By Code --I know this doesn't work
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT: Description of procedure itself**

The procedure takes the `@DateLeft` value (which, as it stands, is **not** a parameter) and uses it as a filter to calculate the distance traveled between that date and today's date (`@DateRight`). You can make up the calculation part if you want. I'm more concerned with the approach that I should take to set `@DateLeft` to each of the different dates for each of the codes, without having to repeat the procedure several times.

Comment: Check out `SELECT INTO`:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Comment: @zimdanen Thanks for the reference. Is there another way to do this that doesn't involve creating a separate table to store the dates?

Comment: I think your procedure doesn't need the two parameters you are using.

Comment: @haytem What do you suggest?

Comment: @ic3man7019: your procedure can be used without parameters, and instead of parsing 'Date' rows one by one, you can parse the whole table at once. Now I have no idea what your procedure does, so I can't suggest anything, maybe you can share it with us.

Comment: @haytem I wish I could share the exact code (believe me), but I can't. I'll do my best to explain it. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @haytem The question has been edited. If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by 'each of the codes'?  Are you wanting to loop through the records in SampleTable?  or what?

Comment: @devlincarnate I mean each of the codes in the `Code` column. They will have different dates. So, I need to be able to set `@DateLeft` to each of the dates in the `Date` column.

Comment: @ic3man7019 - i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DateLeft DATE;
SELECT @DateLeft = [Date] From SampleTable Group By Code
```

You can set the variable value using this syntax.

**Update based on OP's update:**

The OP's updated request is not abundantly clear, but I believe a loop may do the trick.

```
DECLARE @DateLeft DATE;
DECLARE @Level INT = 0;
WHILE @Level < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SampleTable)
BEGIN
    SELECT @DateLeft = [Date] From SampleTable Group By Code;
    --do something with @DateLeft

    SET @Level = @Level + 1;
END
```

Comment: I think this is not what he is looking for

Comment: @haytem - how so?  OP wants to get the value of [Date] from a table into a variable.  That's what this does.

Comment: @devlincarnate I would like to be able to get the value, do the calculation, then get the next value for the next code and do its calculation. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: What do you mean by the  'next code' ?  Are you wanting to loop through the records in SampleTable?  Or some other 'code'?

Comment: Allow me to try this. Thanks.

Comment: @devlincarnate Allow me to make another edit to the question that I think will help.

Comment: @devlincarnate I have edited the question again. I want to be able to put the result that the procedure yields into the `Distance` column for each date. Since the date will change for each record in the table, how can I go about getting the result for each record individually, without calling the procedure over and over again? By calling the procedure multiple times, it uses whatever date you pass it to calculate ALL of the records' distance values. I want it so that the value for `@DateLeft` will change for each record in the table.

Comment: Then you will want to iterate over the table limiting by ID, or whatever the unique key is for your table.  Since it's possible the key may not be sequential, you will need to use a [cursor](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-what-is-a-cursor/).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it like a loop you might need to look at SQL Server Cursor.

If you don't need a loop you can always select value to a variable like this:

```
declare @DateLeft as datetime;
SELECT @DateLeft =  Date 
From SampleTable
Group By Code;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way that I could make `@'DateLeft` change its value for each different code? Each code has a different date value that must be taken into account when the calculation takes place.

Comment: I think you need to look at SQL Server Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for?:

```
select
    (
        /* calculation goes here */
        select sum(m.TraveledDistance) as Distance
        from MyTable m
        /* correlate the subquery on t.Code and max t.Date */
        where m.Code = t.Code and m.Time between max(t.Date) and getdate() 
    ) as Calculation,
    t.Code
from SampleTable t
group by t.Code
```

Answer (score -2):

Your approach works as follows:  SET @DateLeft = (Select Date From Sample Table Group By Code)